# asp.net regularexpressionvalidator not working as expected

Tags: asp.net, regex

I've the following textbox control and regular expression validator:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ATextBox" style="width:400px;"/>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="ATextBoxRegularExpressionValidator" Display="Dynamic"
                    ControlToValidate="ATextBox" ValidationExpression="^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|((https?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[-\w ;,./?%&=]*)?)$" 
                    ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:Antivirus, AVURL_InvalidLink %>">
                                       </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

The regular expression is:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|((https?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[-\w ;,./?%&=]*)?)$
```

which works when I test it with any validator expression testers such as:

http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Basically the regular expression should accept all URL's and hostnames.

So good:
google
google.com
http://google.com
https://google.com

Bad:

```
<asp>http://google.com</asp>
```

Anyone any idea why my regular expression when running in the app is failing the following: 
google.com
http://google.com
https://google.com

**UPDATE**

I've managed to solve my problem.... the regular expression that is doing what I want to do is:

^((https?://)?([\w-]+.)*[\w-]+(/[-\w ;,./?%&=]*)?)$

Thanks for your help

Comment: You have http://g oogle.com as good and bad, can you just be a little more clear on what you want to validate as good

Comment: Just updated.. bad would be the string: <asp>http://google.com</asp>

Answer (score 1):

I would say the first problem is that the `/` need escaped:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|((https?:\/\/)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(\/[-\w ;,.\/?%&=]*)?)$
```

The next problem of interest is that the Regex you currently have doesn't really ever match the entire URL, it matches and groups portions. But maybe that's what you want.

Here is a [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/6V30C749mQ) with the modified Regex and values you noted.

Comment: I added the escape characters. Unfortunately only 'google' is being matched. All others are failing